# Magicento 2.9 in PHPStorm 2016.1.2 causes an error (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: phpstorm

Magicento causes a lot of erorrs like below. Errors went one by one with the same text.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.magicento.models.xml.config.AdminRoutersIdArgsModulesXmlTag PluginClassLoader[Magicento, 2.9.0]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.magicento.helpers.JavaHelper.classExists(JavaHelper.java:42)
    at com.magicento.models.xml.MagentoXml._getClassNameFromTag(MagentoXml.java:174)
    at com.magicento.models.xml.MagentoXml._createChildren(MagentoXml.java:94)
    at com.magicento.models.xml.MagentoXml._createChildren(MagentoXml.java:114)
    at com.magicento.models.xml.MagentoXml._createChildren(MagentoXml.java:114)
    at com.magicento.models.xml.MagentoXml._createChildren(MagentoXml.java:114)
    at com.magicento.models.xml.MagentoXml._createChildren(MagentoXml.java:114)
    at com.magicento.models.xml.MagentoXml._create(MagentoXml.java:74)
    at com.magicento.models.xml.MagentoXml._init(MagentoXml.java:61)
    at com.magicento.models.xml.config.MagentoConfigXml._init(MagentoConfigXml.java:48)
    at com.magicento.models.xml.MagentoXml.<init>(MagentoXml.java:56)
    at com.magicento.models.xml.config.MagentoConfigXml.<init>(MagentoConfigXml.java:39)
    at com.magicento.models.xml.MagentoXmlFactory.getInstance(MagentoXmlFactory.java:56)
    at com.magicento.models.MagentoFactoryCache.findClassesForFactory(MagentoFactoryCache.java:43)
    at com.magicento.MagicentoProjectComponent.findClassesOfFactoryUri(MagicentoProjectComponent.java:463)
    at com.magicento.MagicentoProjectComponent.findClassesOfFactoryUri(MagicentoProjectComponent.java:467)
    at com.magicento.extensions.FactoryTypeProvider2.getClasses(FactoryTypeProvider2.java:668)
    at com.magicento.extensions.FactoryTypeProvider2.getBySignature(FactoryTypeProvider2.java:482)
    at com.jetbrains.php.PhpIndexImpl.getBySignatureInternal(PhpIndexImpl.java:420)
    at com.jetbrains.php.PhpIndexImpl.getBySignature(PhpIndexImpl.java:306)
    at com.jetbrains.php.PhpIndexImpl.completeType(PhpIndexImpl.java:79)
    at com.jetbrains.php.lang.psi.resolve.types.PhpType.globalLocationAware(PhpType.java:380)
    at com.jetbrains.php.lang.psi.elements.impl.MemberReferenceImpl.resolveGlobal(MemberReferenceImpl.java:145)
    at com.jetbrains.php.lang.psi.elements.impl.PhpReferenceImpl$1.resolve(PhpReferenceImpl.java:144)
    at com.jetbrains.php.lang.psi.elements.impl.PhpReferenceImpl$1.resolve(PhpReferenceImpl.java:141)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache$3.compute(ResolveCache.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$2.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:112)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.a(ResolveCache.java:139)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolveWithCaching(ResolveCache.java:167)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolveWithCaching(ResolveCache.java:159)
    at com.jetbrains.php.lang.psi.elements.impl.PhpReferenceImpl.multiResolve(PhpReferenceImpl.java:136)
    at com.jetbrains.php.lang.psi.elements.impl.PhpReferenceImpl.resolve(PhpReferenceImpl.java:122)
    at com.jetbrains.php.lang.annotator.PhpAnnotatorVisitor.checkAccessModifiers(PhpAnnotatorVisitor.java:411)
    at com.jetbrains.php.lang.annotator.PhpAnnotatorVisitor.visitPhpMethodReference(PhpAnnotatorVisitor.java:393)
    at com.jetbrains.php.lang.psi.elements.impl.MethodReferenceImpl.accept(MethodReferenceImpl.java:29)
    at com.jetbrains.php.lang.annotator.PhpAnnotator.annotate(PhpAnnotator.java:19)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DefaultHighlightVisitor.a(DefaultHighlightVisitor.java:135)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DefaultHighlightVisitor.visit(DefaultHighlightVisitor.java:99)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.a(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:351)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.access$100(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:62)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$3.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:280)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.a(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:305)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.access$200(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:62)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$4.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:311)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.analyze(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:750)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.a(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:308)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.access$200(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:62)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$4.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:311)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DefaultHighlightVisitor.analyze(DefaultHighlightVisitor.java:83)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.a(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:308)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.a(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:277)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.collectInformationWithProgress(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:216)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.doCollectInformation(ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.java:82)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:70)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass$1$1.run(PassExecutorService.java:444)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1178)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass$1.run(PassExecutorService.java:435)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.a(PassExecutorService.java:432)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:408)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:206)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:858)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1687)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1642)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:108)
```

> java version "1.8.0_92"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: You probably want to raise this question with the developer of Magicento rather than on here. More likely to get a useful response there.

Comment: Yes, I did that. Just drop a question here with a chance that somebody saw sth similar

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved in 2.9.4 version.
Thanks to author.